# move occurs because value has type `RefCell<...>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Tags: rust

**UPDATE**
My real problem was caused by my IDE having auto-imported `use std::borrow::{Borrow, BorrowMut};`.
With this line, the accepted answer [also doesn't compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=%23!%5Ballow(dead_code)%5D%0A%23!%5Ballow(unused_variables)%5D%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Arc%3A%3ARc%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Acell%3A%3ARefCell%3B%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aborrow%3A%3A%7BBorrow%2C%20BorrowMut%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Astruct%20InstanceContext%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20i32%2C%0A%20%20%20%20instances%3A%20Option%3CVec%3CString%3E%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20instance_context%20%3D%20Rc%3A%3Anew(RefCell%3A%3Anew(InstanceContext%20%7B%20id%3A%205%2C%20instances%3A%20None%20%7D))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20instance_context.borrow_mut().instances%20%3D%20Some(vec!%5BString%3A%3Afrom(%22abc%22)%5D)%3B%0A%7D).
The solution was removing the line.

---

I'm getting the following error message:

```
15 |     instance_context.into_inner().instances = Some(vec![String::from("abc")]);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `RefCell<InstanceContext>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

and I have no idea why, or how to fix the code.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=%23!%5Ballow(dead_code)%5D%0A%23!%5Ballow(unused_variables)%5D%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Arc%3A%3ARc%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Acell%3A%3ARefCell%3B%0A%0Astruct%20InstanceContext%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20i32%2C%0A%20%20%20%20instances%3A%20Option%3CVec%3CString%3E%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20instance_context%20%3D%20Rc%3A%3Anew(RefCell%3A%3Anew(InstanceContext%20%7B%20id%3A%205%2C%20instances%3A%20None%20%7D))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20clojures%20are%20created%20that%20use%20instance_context%2C%20which%20does%20not%20yet%20have%20%27instances%27%20set%0A%20%20%20%20instance_context.into_inner().instances%20%3D%20Some(vec!%5BString%3A%3Afrom(%22abc%22)%5D)%3B%0A%7D%0A):

```
#![allow(dead_code)]
#![allow(unused_variables)]

use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct InstanceContext {
    id: i32,
    instances: Option<Vec<String>>,
}

fn main() {
    let instance_context = Rc::new(RefCell::new(InstanceContext { id: 5, instances: None }));
    // clojures are created that use instance_context, which does not yet have 'instances' set
    instance_context.into_inner().instances = Some(vec![String::from("abc")]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`into_inner()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.into_inner) method will consume the `RefCell` instance to give you the wrapped value.

To achieve that, it requires you to have ownership over the instance of `RefCell`. But you don't have that as it is within `Rc` and unless you consume the `Rc` as well to get ownership of `RefCell`, you can't call `into_inner()`.

---

In your code, due to deref coersion, you get immutable ref to the inside `RefCell` so you can only call methods that accept `&self`.

If you want mutate the contents inside `RefCell`, you can do it as follows:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]
#![allow(unused_variables)]

use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct InstanceContext {
    id: i32,
    instances: Option<Vec<String>>,
}

fn main() {
    let instance_context = Rc::new(RefCell::new(InstanceContext { id: 5, instances: None }));
    instance_context.borrow_mut().instances = Some(vec![String::from("abc")]);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b140f7877278e81308fa239f01a191f7)

[`borrow_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) takes an immutable ref to `RefCell` instance and lets you get a mutable ref to the wrapped value with which you can mutate the contents of the wrapped value.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. I had already tried that, but your code led me to identify the cause. Apparently my IDE had auto-imported "use std::borrow::{Borrow, BorrowMut};", and this caused the inability to compile with .borrow_mut as well.